# Eloquent Filtering Collection with Eager Loading

Tags: php, orm, eloquent

I have been looking online and can't seem to figure this out.
I have two tables: Teams and TeamMembers.  A team can have one or more team members, so it is a one-to-many relationship.

Here is the basic of the two tables:

```
   class Team extends Base\EloquentBase
       {
          // Relationship
          public function teamMembers()
          {
            return $this->hasMany('TeamClock\Eloquent\Models\TeamMember', 'team_id', 'team_id');
          }
       }

       class TeamMember extends Base\EloquentBase
       {
          // Relationship
          public function team()
          {
            return $this->belongsTo('TeamClock\Eloquent\Models\Team', 'team_id', 'team_id');
          
          // Scope
          public function scopeHasDailyPerDiem($q)
          {
            return $q->where('is_daily_per_diem', '>', 0);
          }
       }
```

As you can see, I have a scope in the TeamMember class, and I want to get all teams with team members who have column "is_daily_per_diem" is greater than 0.

I have a test controller, and I'm dumping out the results:

```
$teams = Team::has('teamMembers')->with(array('teamMembers' => function($query){
                $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
        }))->get();
```

Here is what I'm getting when dumping out:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 55
            [phase_id] => value
            [team_name] => value
            [team_member_quota] => value
            [team_member_overstaff] => value
            [published] => value
            [tools_required] => value
            [dress_code] => value
            [special_instructions] => value 
            [team_members] => Array
                (
                )

        )
...
[41] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 115
            [phase_id] => value
            [team_name] => value
            [team_member_quota] => value
            [team_member_overstaff] => 0
            [published] => 1
            [tools_required] => 
            [dress_code] => 
            [special_instructions] => 
            [team_members] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [team_member_id] => value
                            [team_id] => 115
                            [position_id] => value
                            [employee_id] => value
                            [team_auth_id] => 1
                            [progress_auth_id] => 2
                            [is_daily_per_diem] => 1
                            [daily_per_diem] => 60.00
                            [pay_type_id] => 1
                            [flat_rate] => 
                            [is_active] => 0
                            [per_diem_beg_date] => 
                            [per_diem_end_date] => 
                            [beg_shift_id] => 
                            [end_shift_id] => 
                            [assign_email_guid] => value
                        )

                )

        )
```

As you can see, I'm getting a mixture of teams with team members(that is daily per diem > 0) and teams with empty team members.

Is there a way to eliminate teams with empty team members?

I also tried this and other stuff in my test controller:

```
$teams = Team::whereHas('teamMembers', function($query){
            $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
        })->get();
```

but this is returning an array of all team members with "is per daily diem" greater than zero, but I'm not getting any team information:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 55
            [phase_id] => value
            [team_name] => value
            [team_member_quota] => value
            [team_member_overstaff] => value
            [published] => value
            [tools_required] => value
            [dress_code] => value
            [special_instructions] => value
        )
...
 [36] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 115
            [phase_id] => value
            [team_name] => value
            [team_member_quota] => value
            [team_member_overstaff] => value
            [published] => value
            [tools_required] => value
            [dress_code] => value
            [special_instructions] => value
        )
```

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there...

If you want to filter teams and eager load members:

```
$teams = Team::with('teamMembers')->whereHas('teamMembers', function($query){
             $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
         })->get();
```

And if you want to filter teams and the eager loaded members:

```
$teams = Team::with(['teamMembers' => function($query){
             $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
         }])->whereHas('teamMembers', function($query){
             $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
         })->get();
```

If you want to reduce duplicate code with the second code block, put the filter closure in a variable:

```
$filter = function($query){
    $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
};

$teams = Team::with(['teamMembers' => $filter])
             ->whereHas('teamMembers', $filter)
             ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! The first option didn't work because I'm getting all teams with team members with or without per diems, but the second one is the one I needed!!!

Comment: You're welcome. But I'm pretty sure the first one would get you the right *teams* but with all their associated members regardless of per diems. Anyways, glad I could help!

Comment: Ok...I will look into it with more details. In the meantime, I got my acceptance!

Answer (score 0):

define a class which implements Scope interface

class TeamFilterScope implements Scope{

```
     public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model){
     $builder->hasDailyPerDiem()
    }
}
```

in you model's boot

```
protected function static boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new TeamFilterScope());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reluctant to use the same query twice - to get all Teams with team members taht fit, and then again to get all the teammember...

So I Get all the Teams and eagerload members with DailyPerDiems and then filter out all teams that have no members:

```
$teams = Team::with('teamMembers'=> function($query){
             $query->hasDailyPerDiem();
           })
         ->get()
         ->reject(function($team){
              return $team->teamMembers->count()<1;
           });
```

I imagine its less trips to the database at the slightly higher cost of having to fetch some teams I ultimately don't need. But most of the time in such cases, that cost is negligible.